# Why is this not return the result from the XML feed?

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

So i have this feed, I have shrunk the nodes that are not needed.

```
<ArrayOfService xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusExpress.ClassLibrary" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Service z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<EntityKey z:Id="i2" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
  <a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
  <a:EntityKeyValues>
    <a:EntityKeyMember>
      <a:Key>serviceId</a:Key>
      <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">1149</a:Value>
    </a:EntityKeyMember>
  </a:EntityKeyValues>
  <a:EntitySetName>ServiceSet</a:EntitySetName>
</EntityKey>
<client z:Id="i3">
  <EntityKey z:Id="i4" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
    <a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
    <a:EntityKeyValues>
      <a:EntityKeyMember>
        <a:Key>clientId</a:Key>
        <a:Value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"></a:Value>
      </a:EntityKeyMember>
    </a:EntityKeyValues>
    <a:EntitySetName>ClientSet</a:EntitySetName>
  </EntityKey>
  <OnlineOrdersEmailAddress></OnlineOrdersEmailAddress>
  <SiriEndPointUrl>/DataBroker/</SiriEndPointUrl>
  <clientId>brightonbuses</clientId>
  <clientName>brightonbuses</clientName>
  <clientRole />
  <customers />
  <emailDistributionList />
  <emailNewsletter />
  <emailTemplate />
  <facebookAccessToken>226218420727119|9fab190dcc99dc2750006a31.3-642660078|191977440844064|WaOZ-7z6_ih2OwHmerQ95uz0nFU</facebookAccessToken>
  <facebookId>191977440844064</facebookId>
  <fareMatrix />
  <newsCategory />
  <newsletter />
  <password />
  <pdfDirectoryPath>C:\buscms\wwwroot\operators\\data-files\pdfs</pdfDirectoryPath>
  <pdfDirectoryUrl>http:///uploadedfiles</pdfDirectoryUrl>
  <primaryEmailAddress>info@buses.co.uk</primaryEmailAddress>
  <primaryWebAddress>http://www.buses.co.uk</primaryWebAddress>
  <realtimeUrl>http://buses.citytransport.org.uk/smartinfo/service/jsp?stName=#gpsStopName#&amp;olifServerId=182&amp;autorefresh=0&amp;default_autorefresh=20&amp;routeId=182%2F#serviceName#&amp;stopId=#gpsStopName#&amp;optDir=#destination#&amp;nRows=10&amp;showArrivals=n&amp;optTime=now&amp;time=&amp;allLines=#allLines#</realtimeUrl>
  <services>
    <Service z:Ref="i1" />
    <Service z:Id="i5">
      <EntityKey z:Id="i6" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
        <a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
        <a:EntityKeyValues>
          <a:EntityKeyMember>
            <a:Key>serviceId</a:Key>
            <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">1150</a:Value>
          </a:EntityKeyMember>
        </a:EntityKeyValues>
        <a:EntitySetName>ServiceSet</a:EntitySetName>
      </EntityKey>
      <client z:Ref="i3" />
      <clientReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
        <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i4" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
      </clientReference>
      <journeyPreferredService />
      <newsArticles />
      <place />
      <primaryUrl>http://www.buses.co.uk/1A</primaryUrl>
      <relativePosition>2</relativePosition>
      <routes>
        <Route z:Id="i7">
          <EntityKey z:Id="i8" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
            <a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
            <a:EntityKeyValues>
              <a:EntityKeyMember>
                <a:Key>routeId</a:Key>
                <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">1236</a:Value>
              </a:EntityKeyMember>
            </a:EntityKeyValues>
            <a:EntitySetName>RouteSet</a:EntitySetName>
          </EntityKey>
          <POI />
          <POILines />
          <dateEffectiveFrom i:nil="true" />
          <dateEffectiveTo i:nil="true" />
          <isLive>true</isLive>
          <relativePosition>0</relativePosition>
          <routeDescription />
          <routeId>1236</routeId>
          <routeMap />
          <routeName>1A Mile Oak - Whitehawk</routeName>
          <route_stop />
          <route_stop_stop />
          <route_stop_timetable_stop />
          <service z:Ref="i5" />
          <serviceReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
            <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i6" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
          </serviceReference>
          <timetables />
          <validDestination>Whitehawk</validDestination>
        </Route>
        <Route z:Id="i9">
          <EntityKey z:Id="i10" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
            <a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
            <a:EntityKeyValues>
              <a:EntityKeyMember>
                <a:Key>routeId</a:Key>
                <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">1232</a:Value>
              </a:EntityKeyMember>
            </a:EntityKeyValues>
            <a:EntitySetName>RouteSet</a:EntitySetName>
          </EntityKey>
          <POI />
          <POILines />
          <dateEffectiveFrom i:nil="true" />
          <dateEffectiveTo i:nil="true" />
          <isLive>true</isLive>
          <relativePosition>0</relativePosition>
          <routeDescription />
          <routeId>1232</routeId>
          <routeMap />
          <routeName>1A Whitehawk - Mile Oak</routeName>
          <route_stop />
          <route_stop_stop />
          <route_stop_timetable_stop />
          <service z:Ref="i5" />
          <serviceReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
            <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i6" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
          </serviceReference>
          <timetables />
          <validDestination>Mile Oak</validDestination>
        </Route>
      </routes>
      <serviceAbbreviatedName />
      <serviceDescription>Whitehawk - County Hospital - City Centre - Hove - Portslade - Mile Oak</serviceDescription>
      <serviceIconUrl>http://www.buscms.com/uploadedFiles/brightonbuses/service-icons/1A.png</serviceIconUrl>
      <serviceId>1150</serviceId>
      <serviceName>1A</serviceName>
      <serviceNotes />
      <serviceText>Whitehawk - Mile Oak</serviceText>
      <serviceUrls />
    </Service>
```

The service repeats itself.

I then have this code to get the data:

```
 void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Error == null) 
    { 
        if (e.Result != null) 
        { 
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result); 
            XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusExpress.ClassLibrary";
            var routeNames = (from n in doc.Descendants(ns + "ArrayOfService") 
                             select new RootContainer

                             {

                                 Stops = (from s in n.Elements(ns + "Service").Elements(ns + "client").Elements(ns + "services").Elements(ns + "Service").Elements(ns + "Service")

                                          select new Stops

                                          {
                                              StopName = s.Element(ns + "serviceDescription").Value,
                                              serviceIconUrl = s.Element(ns + "Service").Element(ns + "serviceIconUrl").Value,
                                            //  NaptanCode = s.Element(ns + "Service").Element(ns + "serviceIconUrl").Value,

                                             // StopId = s.Element(ns + "stop").Element(ns + "stopId").Value 

                                          }).ToList() 
                             }).Single();


            listBox1.ItemsSource = routeNames.Stops;
```

And its binding like this in the xmal page:

```
   <ListBox x:Name="listBox1"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  Foreground="Red" Height="160" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="-10,0,10,377" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <!-- <TextBlock Text="Bus Stops: "/>-->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StopName}"/>
                    <!--   <TextBlock Text="Timetables: "/>-->
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding serviceIconUrl}"/>                       
                   <!--   <TextBlock Text="{Binding StopId}"/>-->
                    <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Why do i get no response? I know it's something simple, just can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LINQ query contains too many `Service` elements at the end, which it won't find.

It is currently:

```
n.Elements(ns + "Service")
 .Elements(ns + "client")
 .Elements(ns + "services")
 .Elements(ns + "Service")
 .Elements(ns + "Service")
```

It should be:

```
n.Elements(ns + "Service")
 .Elements(ns + "client")
 .Elements(ns + "services")
 .Elements(ns + "Service")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks i have done that - but i still get an error - An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in BrightonHoveBuses.dll

Comment: @HenryEdwards - That likely means that something (either an element or attribute) you are accessing in your `select` block doesn't exist in the XML document